# Music playback on an old car

Tags: bluetooth, entertainment-system, infotainment

I have a BMW 525i E60 2005 which doesn't have aux , bluetooth or USB. It however does have a CD player which I have been having to use for the time being.

I need a way of playing songs from either bluetooth or a USB stick.

I have already got an FM transmitter but it isnt the solution I'm after for the reasons I explain below.

- I need to be able to select either different folders on the USB or different playlists if using bluetooth.
- I also need to be able to switch through the songs if I want to skip to the next or the previous.

Most FM transmitters allow next and previous however I cant find one that lets me easily select a different folder.

Does anyone have a device in mind that would let me play music whilst having playlist/folder control and music control.

One other thing which is not that necessary but would be great is if this device had the ability to continue the song it was playing instead of restarting the song once the car turns back on.

Thanks.

Comment: Having been in a similar position for my car also from 2005, then you need to look at replacing the head unit to get all the functionality you describe...

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a 1989 Opel Vectra. It didn't have bluetooth, AUX or USB, and I also didn't have the code for the radio and the battery had been flat many times, so obviously even the radio didn't work.

Fortunately, the radio was of standard size and easy to remove. I replaced the radio with an entirely different radio.

In new cars, you cannot do that, because the radio is integrated to the entire car electronics system, i.e. you control the radio from the touchscreen.

But, considering that your car is 2005, perhaps it is old enough to have an interchangeable radio.

Cost of this swap? If you do it yourself, and select a cheap radio unit, $50 - $100.

Comment: Yep, we used to swap out standard DIN head units all the time. Usually to get a CD player instead of the standard cassette player... I feel old!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, unfortunately because of the I drive system in the BMW which has settings and climate control and parking assist etc . I can't simply swap out the head unit or I lose these features.

Comment: Oh, your car is one of the newer ones. Well, then, I guess your solution is to keep in mind the importance of AUX the next time you purchase a new/second-hand car.

Comment: Im unfamiliar with how the iDrive system works but on some cars, like mine, where the head unit controls more than just the audio it is easiest to add a second aftermarket unit and simply wire the audio portions to the new radio. For example, my factory manages the climate control so I have an aftermarket single din mounted further down the dash and I can retain climate control with a better radio

Answer (score 0):

Does your iPod 30 pin port? If it does, you can connect an adapter to it and connector to your phone with Bluetooth.

This article explains that method and basically all the options on [how to connect a phone to a car stereo.](https://www.youcanic.com/article/play-music-phone-car)

Comment: I think E60s, at least of that age, don't support the proper audio bluetooth profiles, only the hands-free profile, so your sound will come out as mono only from the speaker(s) on which hands-free sound is enabled (basically front driver-side).

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using an iPod, there are iPod adapters for E60 that you can find on the internets and install yourself. If you're not an adventurous type, your BMW dealer will gladly install one for you as well. With such an adapter iPod playlists are fully integrated with the entertainment module and allow you to browse through them and control playback in various ways.